# Render a page at run time from dynamically loaded assembly in Blazor app

Tags: c#, .net-core, blazor, webassembly, blazor-server-side

I am creating a modular Blazor app, which dynamically loads all the external assemblies (i.e. modules) from a location.

Then I want to show module names in NavMenu of the Blazor app.

When user clicks on a module name, then browser renders a page/component from that module with in Index page of my Blazor app.

Need help in doing that

Comment: Why can't both be selected  ? I'm learning Blazor server-side and Blazor client-side, and I'm investing in both equally. So it is important to know how to code in both, support and lack of support, etc.

Answer (score 7):

Lazy loading assemblies is not yet available for blazor. All assemblies your project depends on will be loaded on start.
This feature should be implemented in .Net 5 Release https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/5465

### Update Blazor 5 Preview

[Mike S.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1239531/mike-s) comments with the doc url to the [Lazy load assemblies in ASP.NET Core Blazor WebAssembly](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/webassembly-lazy-load-assemblies?view=aspnetcore-5.0).

Comment: Just an update, it looks like it is now available in 5.0.   Here is the documentation.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/webassembly-lazy-load-assemblies?view=aspnetcore-5.0

Answer (score 0):

Blazor team expressed their concerns to make this part of the framework.

Luckily, there are some nice libraries to do this. I'm personally maintaining one of them, you can have a look at it.

https://github.com/isc30/blazor-lazy-loading